# Skip a Level in LaTex enumitem

Tags: enumitem

I have a 3-level list with the levels formatted as follows:

```
A.

  1.

    (a)
```

I would like to skip a level at one point, so that I have the following:

```
A.
    1. 
        (a)
        (b)
B.
        (a)
        (b)
C.
     1.
     2.
```

Notice that I don't want to use the 1. (i.e. enumii) in the level that follows "B." and just use level 3 as the next set of labels.

I tried to use the following:

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \def\labelenumiii{(\alph{enumiii})}
```

But that didn't produce the result I was looking for.  It ignored the \def and just  used level 2 (enumii).

Comment: Maybe item with no label? `\item[]`

Answer (score 10):

Like this (except the label format; I am using the default ones; see edit below).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item 
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item 
      \begin{enumerate}
      \item 
      \item 
      \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
  \item 
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item[]
      \begin{enumerate}
      \item 
      \item 
      \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
  \item
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item 
    \item 
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** If you want, you can change the label format using on preamble

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\Alph*.}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=\arabic*.}
\setlist[enumerate,3]{label=(\alph*)}
```

[image]